# CSS not applying to nested child divs

Tags: php, css, html, nested

I have a few nested divs on a website I am creating with the Joomla engine. The problem lies mainly in the fact that the plugins themselves nest 2 divs inside my already created div "banner", meaning I do not have access to these two divs. Within them is the small, rectangular image. This image should help you see my issue (I'd post an embedded image but you know, apparently I need 10 rep):

http://www.nerfarena.net/SiteImage.PNG

I don't want the banner ad butted against the search bar. But the three nested divs will not increase in height no matter what CSS properties I modify. Even #banner won't budge. They all seem to size themselves to the minimum needed (bottom of the search bar + banner ad's height). I'm looking for a way around this so any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Here is the chunk of the php file where the divs I am concerned about are:

`

```
     <!-- Logo -->
    <div id="logo">

    <?php if ($logo && $logoimage == 1): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>"><img src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($logo); ?>"  alt="<?php echo $sitename; ?>" /></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if (!$logo || $logoimage == 0): ?>

        <?php if ($sitetitle): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($sitetitle); ?></a><br/>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($sitedescription): ?>
            <div class="sitedescription"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($sitedescription); ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    <!-- Search -->
    <div id="search">       
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-0" />
    </div>

    <!-- Banner -->
    <div id="banner" style= "text-align: right;">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="banner-position" />
    </div> 
</div>
```

`

Comment: post the rendered html and the css that's not working.

Comment: does the newly created div's have any classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [sibling selectors](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/) for CSS. Sometimes it helps me fix the alignments of divs.

Comment: Actually, this in combination with clearing out a certain cached value helped immensely. Once the values were actually updating the child selector made it easy to directly modify those divs that Joomla was making for me. Thanks a bunch.